# Genetic algorithm - Subset sum problem

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, subset-sum

I have to do a project which using a genetic algorithm solves the subset sum problem. Unfortunately, when coding the algorithm I found a big problem ...

My algorithm:

- as long as no solution was found and the number of steps is smaller than steps do:
- calculate the probability and then distribution function for each chromosome
- perform selection (roulette)
- select n chromosomes to be crossed
- perform the crossing (the crossing point is selected randomly)
- select m chromosomes to mutation
- perform mutations
- if you found a solution then stop

(Algorithm was taken from the book "Genetic Algorithms + Data Structures = Evolution Programs, Chapter 2 ")
Variables such as population size, amount of data, scope of data collection, number of steps, the number of mutations (in step), the number of crossings (in a step) is set rigidly in the program options.

The problem is that after a certain (relatively small) number of steps in the population all the chromosomes are identical. The problem illustrates this graph:
http://imageshack.us/m/96/7693/wykresb.png

What I'm doing wrong? How to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here You can find logs from my app:
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/391318/

I think that roulette is not the best solution (as deong said). Mutations also need to improve.

Comment: What language are you using to implement the algorithm? It sounds like an issue with the crossover and mutation phase. To troubleshoot turn off each of these phases and try and isolate the problem. I imagine it is something to do with the variables you are using and that you are not taking deep copies of chromosomes when applying these operators on your population..

Comment: I think the issue may well be with your implementation, you would need to post your code.

Comment: @Gordon Murray Dent - I'm using Java. I will check this.

Comment: @Toby Allen - My project contains few classes and isn't well coded :(. In my opinion posting the source code is pointless.

Comment: @Ziem, how do you know the problem isnt with your implementation?

Comment: It was a bug in the implementation and I also improved my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before, I wish it s the same as your's

First, you need to check (using any measuring metric) if chromosome A is better than chromosome B. This let you have a strict order of the chromosomes of your population and be able to sort your population.

Then, when you produce a new chromosome (either by mutation or crossover) you may be producing a chromosome that already exist in your population. Make sure not to include this in your population list.

In other words, make sure your list always contains different chromosomes and always sorted from best to worst !

Note:
The genetic algorithms I work with are usually like this (this is the most general algorithm and most used):

- create P different chromosomes and
  add them to list Pop;

  1. while (no optimal solution is found && number of iteration < LIM)
  2. create new chromosomes using crossover, mutation or any other
     methods;
  3. add the created chromosome to list Pop
  4. sort the list Pop (from best-fit to worst-fit)
  5. select the first P different chromosomes and discard all other
     from Pop.
  6. end while

Comment: I used some of Your tips in my algorithm and now it is working OK (I think so :))!

Answer (score 3):

Here's (potentially) the problem. Disclaimer is of course that you may just have a buggy program.

Roulette wheel selection is just terrible. The problem is that early on in a run, the distribution of fitness values is random. You have some awful solutions and some that are reasonable OK in comparison. You don't expect any of them to be very good, but you would expect some of them to be *much* better than others.

Roulette wheel selection takes these relative differences in probabilities and amplifies them. If you have a population size of 100, and one individual has a fitness five times better than any others, it will be selected five times as often. With typically mild mutation rates, you end up quickly in a situation where you choose the same individual twice for recombination, produce some new identical offspring, make very minor changes (maybe), and then put them back into the population. Because you're still early in the run, most solutions are still bad, so where you did have one above average solution, you selected it into five above average solutions, bred them to get ten above average solutions, and then started the process all over again. These solutions can very quickly take over the entire population if you aren't really careful with designing your set of operators, even though all the algorithm knows is that they're better than the really crappy solutions it has otherwise seen.

The solution is to use a better selection operator. Binary tournament selection is faster, easier to code, and applies a much more tolerable selection pressure. There is also rank-biased selection which selects proportionally by fitness ranking rather than absolute differences.

**Edit**: This isn't to say you *can't* use proportional selection. Just that it is very prone to premature convergence and to use it effectively, you typically have to build an entire set of operators with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When applying genetic algorithms, it can happen that the algorithm gets stuck at local optima. However, one is interested in the global optimum (or rather an approximation to such an optimum).

Local optima can be avoided by:

- A higher mutation rate
- A different cross-over function

Moreover, it may be useful to *kill clones*. That means you "quickly" look at your population after each iteration and do not allow for clones. By quickly I mean that you just look for approximate clones, because checking for exact clones would take O(m*n^2), where n is your population size and m is the size of a chromosome. 
This method helped me in a different problem where I was facing clones as well.

Hope this helped,
Christian

**EDIT**

It would also be nice if you could post your cross-over function. Preferably not as code, but in plain english text. The cross-over function is the critical part of a genetic algorithm.

Comment: How to replace clones? Because my population size should be the same in every step. My crossing function works in this way: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/391131/ .

Comment: @Ziem - Okay so you have binary arrays as chromosomes. That's a good point to start from. What exactly do the 1's and 0's represent? Also try your code with a higher number of chrossing points: i.e. ch1 = 101|11|001, ch2 = 011|01|010, Offspring = 101|01|001.

Comment: @Ziem - Oh and: Why do you have two offsprings? Do you discard the offspring with the lowest fitness out of the two, or do you keep both?

Comment: @Ziem - As for how to replace clones: Basically after each iteration of the main loop you sort the chromosomes by fitness. Say your population is initially size = 100. With your crossing function, you would get 300 chromosomes after the cross-over. Of these 300 chromosomes there are a lot of "Clones". Detect them (efficiently) and delete them from your population. It works like evolution in the real world: If we all were clones of each other, all genes of our children would be the same. That wouldn't be good.

Comment: @Christian - My set, e.g S={-3, -1, 2, 2, 5}. Genotype ch1 = 10101 means that phenotype of this chromosome is {-3, 2, 5}

Comment: @Ziem - I think either you have a programming bug or (and I think this is more likely) your crossing function is not good enough. I presume initially you generate 100 chromosomes completely at random: 1010010101, 101011110, ... ; From those random chromosomes you end up in a local optimum after a short amount of time. That is because your crossing function does not enable a big variety for the possible offsprings. My suggestion: Either try a different way of crossing two chromosomes (books wont help here, just try your own ideas) or simply get rid of clones.

Comment: @Ziem - A better cross-over function is far better than deleting clones! Because deleting clones is taking a lot of performance and just a workaround to your problem, not a solution!

Comment: You can have the greatest crossover operator the world has ever known, but if you apply very high amounts of selection pressure, it isn't going to matter. You'll converge very quickly, and once you converge, crossover can't create new alleles.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! I fixed some bugs in implementation and I used some of Your suggestions and I think my algorithm now is working OK. Please check graph: http://imageshack.us/f/98/wykresik.png/